# React Native (JSX) string replace

Tags: react-native, reactjs

Is it possible to modify a string in JSX? For instance I want to search and replace the string in the image url.

```js
  renderMovie: function(movie) {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Image
          source={{uri: movie.posters.thumbnail}}
          style={styles.thumbnail}
        />
        <View style={styles.rightContainer}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>{movie.title}</Text>
          <Text style={styles.year}>{movie.year}</Text>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
```

I want to modify the url here ( Code taken from here https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tutorial.html#content)

```
movie.posters.thumbnail
```

Comment: So what is your problem? you can do it easily like: `movie.posters.thumbnail + '&arg=1'`

Comment: @Cherniv: I wanted to find and replace parts of the string in the url. The Image is in .gif I want the url to be .jpeg

Comment: Element in react is immutable, you need to re-create it to modify properties. Read here http://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/03/03/react-v0.13-rc2.html#react.cloneelement

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and solved it using [react-string-replace](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-string-replace)

```
npm i react-string-replace
```

I rovides a simple way to safely do string replacement with React components.